# How do I make the .left class appear below the header but keep the header position as fixed?

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I am new to css and trying to learn positioning.  I've set up the following stylesheet:

```
div{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#header{
    width: 550px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.left{

    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 300px;
    width:275px;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    background-color: #0000ff;
    width: 275px;
   height: 300px;
}

#footer{
    clear: both;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 550px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does it have to do with tie fixed positioning of the header tab that is making the .left class appear at the very top.  How do I make the .left class appear below the header but keep the header position as fixed?

Thanks

Comment: Change position to fixed? http://jsfiddle.net/3fC5b/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position `fixed` pulls the content out of the traditional flow just like position `absolute` does. Assuming you want to fix it to the top, you need to also add `top: 0;` so that it knows where to stick. Here's some updated code that should solve your problems.

Styles:

```
div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#header {
    width: 550px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#content {
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 110px;
}

#content:after {
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.left, .right {
    height: 300px;
    width: 275px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: #0000ff;
}

#footer{
    background-color: orange;
    width: 550px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Also, I would recommend putting your floating elements into a container of their own and add your `margin-top` to that container. You'll also see that I added a clear fix to the `#content` div so that it wasn't necessary on the footer.

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutelyfixed positioned elements are removed from the so called document flow. Other elements do no longer care for them - for them, they don't exist. In other words: Your described behavior is supposed to be like that.

You could push the other elements down the page with margin-top, though.

```
.left, .right {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I don't have any absolute position elements?

Comment: I'm sorry for that, but it actually doesn't make any difference. Same thing goes for `position: fixed;` elements. :)

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way to make a div behave as fixed but not be removed from the workflow?

Comment: No, there isn't. That would not be logical. Elements get laid out on the page one by one.